# Java Out of Bounds Error

Tags: java

When i Enter 1 record and I choose 1. Add Record it always have a error. And when i Enter 2 records I can only Enter 1 record and when i choose 1. Add Records again it says OutofBounds. How can i fix that error ?

```
public static int recno=0, recsize, choice, i=0;

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
  System.out.print("Enter Number of Records");
  recsize = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
  String EmpNo[] = new String[recsize];

  display_menu(EmpNo,recno);
}

public static void add_Rec(String EmpNo[],  int recno) throws IOException{
  ++recno;
  EmpNo[recno]= "EMP-"+ recno;
  System.out.print("Employee Number: " + EmpNo[recno]);

  System.out.print("\nEmployee Name: ");

  display_menu(EmpNo,recno);
}


public static void display_menu(String EmpNo[],  int recno) throws IOException{
  System.out.println("Main Menu");
  System.out.println("1. Add record");
  System.out.println("Enter Your Choice");
  choice = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
  if (choice==1){
    add_Rec(EmpNo,recno);
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in Java are 0-based.

Comment: check whether your recno < EmpNo.length

Comment: Did you get your answer, or still any issues are there  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the following:

```
++recno;
EmpNo[recno] = "EMP-" + recno;
```

With:

```
if (recno < recsize) {
    EmpNo[recno++] = "EMP-" + recno;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have initialized `recno` to zero.

then when you do this

```
++recno;
```

`recno` values increments to 1.

But in java array index must start with `0`

change `++recno;` to `recno++;`

As the above answer said Also check that the index value should be less then the size of the array like this

```
if(recno<recsize) {
   EmpNo[recno] = "EMP-" + recno;
   System.out.print("Employee Number: " + EmpNo[recno]);
   System.out.print("\nEmployee Name: ");
    display_menu(EmpNo, recno);
 }
```

Comment: Actually the time is posted I saw that you already posted it :p

Comment: AND FYI you are wrong saying that  "in java array index must start with 0"  it itself starts with 0, but you can directly assign arr[1], it will not fail...if in the bounds

Answer (score 0):

OutofBounds Exception is coming as  Java array index must start with 0 which is already mentioned by others.

But I am also interested to know you are calling `display_menu(EmpNo, recno)` recursively but there is no condition when it will end.

Even if you are able to resolve OutofBounds Exception you will stuck in StackOverflowError as you `calling display_menu(EmpNo, recno`) recursively